# Windows has changed to download and install updates automatically?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I religiously have Windows Update set to:

> Check for updates but let me choose whether to download and install them

However, this morning after having booted the machine, I have a notification that updates will be installed "as scheduled" (at 3am)?! And checking my Windows Updates settings, it now states:

> Install updates automatically (recommended)

How? Why has Windows changed this setting seemingly behind my back?!

The only thing I did last night that I think could have triggered this (although I don't think it should have) is that I installed "Windows Movie Maker" (part of the free Windows Live Essentials). Could this have changed my Windows Update settings?!

Comment: It *could* have! You are the best person to find out reall; Why don't you try and un-install it, change your Windows Update settings to what you want, reboot machine. Check all is as it should be, install the Live Essentials, check if the Auto updates has changed, reboot, check if the Auto updates has changed.

Comment: I'd also take a look through the event logs.  You might find something there to explain the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's been over a month but -- after reproducing the issue on 2 different machines -- I can confirm that installing Windows Live Essentials on Windows 7 Pro or Windows 8.1 (both 64 bit) will change your Windows Update settings back to "Install updates automatically" regardless of what they were previously.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this discussion after spotting my update behaviour changing, and can confirm the same behaviour (Oct 2015). I had Windows 7 set to check for updates but to let me choose whether to download them. After installing Windows Movie Maker yesterday, the update settings have changed to automatically download and install. I only realised when I caught Windows in the act.

Bad behaviour from Microsoft, there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer/confirmation. (To the downvoter: This is confirmation of the behaviour hypothesised in my question, it's not simply a "me too" response; it is a valid answer.)